# Schedule R Cron in Centos for Amazon EC2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, cron, rstudio

I am trying to run a cronjob on Centos via crontab on EC2.
For test purpose, I created a R file *Test_for_Cron.R* that does this:

```
x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- x + y
z
```

Let's say I want my script to run every 2 minutes.

By running *getwd()* in RStudio, I found that the path of my .R file is:
***/home/user1/Test_for_Cron.R***

My R script is launched when I run in Centos the following:

```
sudo /home/user1/Test_for_Cron.R
```

When I run in Centos the which command for Rscript I get:

```
> which Rscript
> /usr/bin/Rscript
```

So afer finding all these info I edited the crontab with:
sudo crontab -e
And I entered the following line:

> */2 * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/user1/Test_for_Cron.R

But it does not work... what am I missing ?

Any help much appreciated !

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? Also it seems like you shouldn't run things with Sudo, does `/usr/bin/Rscript /home/user1/Test_for_Cron.R` work?

Comment: no, only if I do: sudo /home/user1/Test_for_Cron.R